# Custom SAML claim configured in multitenant Azure AD app is not copied to this app in another tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, ws-federation, azure-app-registration

We are authenticating users of our application using WS-Federation. Up to now, we used single tenant app, created in Azure AD via App registration. Our application expects to get `user.employeeid` attribute as a SAML claim, and it is configured in a corresponding app in *Enterprise applications* blade (Single sign-on > Attributes & claims). In app manifest (in app registration), `acceptMappedClaims` is set to true, to make this work.

Above configuration works perfectly, and now we want to switch to multi-tenant, and in the application code we set valid issuers to tenants AAA and BBB, where AAA is the original one.

When I sign in as a user from BBB, after I consent the app, `employeeid` claim is not returned. When checking the enterprise app, which was created in BBB after consent, I see that the custom claim is missing, and I have to manually add it. After that, it works perfectly.

Adding the claim manually is not a big problem for me, but I'm curious if it does work that way by design? Do I have to manually add such claims by hand to each tenant which I want to grant access, or maybe I'm missing something, and there is a way to copy such custom claims automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Multitenant** Application:

[image]

Configured SAML claims:

[image]

When I signed in with the home tenant user, the claim is displayed like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=ClientID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=api://xxxx/access_as_user&state=12345&nonce=12345
```

[image]

When I signed in with the other tenant user, ***the access token did not contain the SAML claim***:

[image]

> **Note** that: **By default**, custom claims are tenant specific. If the claims are configured in the tenant A application, then only the claims will be added for tenant A users not other tenant users.

- The custom claims that you have configured in one tenant might not be available in another tenant since each tenant has its own set of claims and attribute mappings.

**Hence** you had to **manually** add the claims in the Enterprise application created in the other tenant and it **cannot be automated**.

I added the custom claim in the Enterprise application created in another tenant:

[image]

Now when I tried to sign-in with ***another tenant user***, **the access token contains SAML claim**:

[image]

Comment: +1 for detailed info and confirmation that it works the same way in your case. While I understand that some claims might be tenant specific, I think that the default attributes supported by Azure AD could be safely exposed as claim in any tenant. If a specific attribute is not used by that tenant, then the claim would contain empty value, and I could handle it appropriately and for example fall back to another claim, or display a message to the user. Did you find the info about not being able to automate the process somewhere in MS docs? Or is it your experience/intuition?

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/891369/multitenant-saml-signing-certificate-and-claims

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I have to accept that it works that way by default then.